# How to use Parse.Object fromJSON?

Tags: javascript, parse-platform

I checked the docs: http://parse.com/docs/js/api/classes/Parse.Object.html#methods_fromJSON

And I did this: `Parse.Object.fromJSON(this.document)`, but I get: `Uncaught Error: Cannot create an object without a className`.

What's the correct way of using this method?

*NOTE:* `console.log(this.document)` outputs: `Object {}` (A Parse object that was previously turned into a JSON object with `toJSON`.)

Answer (score 3):

As the error message says, you're missing a `className` (in your JSON) that tells it what kind of Parse object it is.